# What am I missing: is function composition with multiple arguments possible?

Tags: f#, composition, function-composition

I understand the basics of function composition in F#, as, for example, described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/06/14/function-composition.aspx).

Maybe I am missing something, though.  The `>>` and `<<` operators seem to have been defined with the assumption that each function only takes one argument:

```
> (>>);;
val it : (('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c) = <fun:it@214-13>
> (<<);;
val it : (('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b) = <fun:it@215-14>
```

What I'd like to do, however, is something like the following:

```
let add a b = a + b
let double c = 2*c
let addAndDouble = add >> double   // bad!
```

But even though `add`'s output is of the type required for `double`'s input, that is rejected.

I know that I can rewrite add with one tuple argument:

```
let add (a,b) = a + b
```

Or I can write a new operator for every number of possible arguments to the first function:

```
let inline (>>+) f g x y = g (f x y)
let doubleAdd = add >>+ double
```

But it seems silly!  Is there a better way that I've missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want isn't totally unreasonable, but there would be no way to indicate the type of a generalized composition operator within F#'s type system.  That is, there's no good way to unify

```
(>>) : ('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c
```

and

```
(>>+) : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('c -> 'd) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'd
```

(not to mention the infinitely many higher arity versions).  Therefore, you have no alternative but to define your own additional operators.  In practice, I often find code written in the "pointed" style `let f x y = add x y |> double` more readable than the point-free/"pointless" `let f = add (>>+) double` anyway.

Comment: Especially when you begin having to `flip` your functions.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the types of `>>` and `<<` that you posted above. eg:

```
> (>>);;
val it : (('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c) = <fun:it@214-13>
```

It takes two functions and a value (`'a`) and returns another value. You need something that takes two functions and 2 values. Hence, both `>>` and `<<` don't have the correct type signature.

Your implementation isn't silly at all. It's just that your requirement doesn't come out of the box in F#'s libraries. Be thankful that you have a language which allows you to define your own operators like this :)

Answer (score 4):

How about threading a stack of arguments through?

```
let add = function x :: y :: t -> x + y :: t
let double = function x :: t -> 2 * x :: t
```

Then you can compose arbitrary arity functions:

```
let doubleAdd = add >> double
```

And it works:

```
> doubleAdd [7; 14]
42
```

(see also [F# Function Composition with multiple input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218044/f-function-composition-with-multiple-input-parameters/5738731#5738731))