# SUMPRODUCT in F# without variables

Tags: f#

I have already done some searches, and this question is a duplicate of another post. I am posting this just for future reference.

Is it possible to define SUMPRODUCT without explicitly using variable names x, y?

Original Function:

```
let SUMPRODUCT x y = List.map2 (*) x y |> List.sum
SUMPRODUCT [1;4] [3;25]    // Result: 103
```

I was hoping to do this:

```
// CONTAINS ERROR!
let SUMPRODUCT = (List.map2 (*)) >> List.sum
// CONTAINS ERROR!
```

But F# comes back with an error.

I have already found the solution on another post, but if you have any suggestions please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function composition only works when the input function takes a single argument. However, in your example, the result of `List.map2 (*)` is a function that  takes two separate arguments and so it cannot be easily composed with `List.sum` using `>>`.

There are various ways to work around this if you really want, but I would not do that. I think `>>` is nice in a few rare cases where it fits nicely, but trying to over-use it leads to unreadable mess.

In some functional languages, the core library defines helpers for turning function with two arguments into a function that takes a tuple and vice versa.

```
let uncurry f (x, y) = f x y
let curry f x y = f (x, y)
```

You could use those two to define your `sumProduct` like this:

```
let sumProduct = curry ((uncurry (List.map2 (*))) >> List.sum)
```

Now it is point-free and understanding it is a fun mental challenge, but for all practical purposes, nobody will be able to understand the code and it is also longer than your original explicit version:

```
let sumProduct x y = List.map2 (*) x y |> List.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this post:

[What am I missing: is function composition with multiple arguments possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446199/what-am-i-missing-is-function-composition-with-multiple-arguments-possible?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Sometimes "pointed" style code is better than "pointfree" style code, and there is no good way to unify the type difference of the original function to what I hope to achieve.